# How to remove the StatusBar on top of the frame on codenameone iOS Theme

Tags: codenameone

The top statusbar always shown, when I use iOS native theme. I search around and found no solution for my javascript build apps. This is because javascript build use iOS as its default theme.

Any solution to hide the top statusbar on iOS theme?

Kindly advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a constant to your theme "paintsTitleBarBool=false" and it will remove the StatusBar

Comment: Yes, it solved! It was wasting my time for few days to figure out..
Thank you!